# How to run a specif .bashrc code only the first time konsole is opened

Tags: linux, bash, shell, konsole

I have a chunk of code in my .bashrc, everytime one runs the shell (I usually use konsole) a switch case appears giving options of which branch or trunk to use. Example:

```
1) V0230
2) V0300
3) Dev

Enter Option: __
```

$PROJECT_HOME and others variables are set upon the choise made.

The annoying thing in this is that it appears everytime I open a new tab the same screen is printed.
But yet I want to open a new konsole and use a different branch, so, simple export a variabe can not be the solution

Must have a way to run this code only when a konsole new screen is open. Maybe making `alias konsole=konsole --run <desired-function>`. The konsole's documentation doesn't give a help, theres not even a `man konsole` just `konsole --help`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an alias:

```
$ alias konsole_select_branch='SELECT_BRANCH=true konsole'
```

and in your `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -n "$SELECT_BRANCH" ]
then
   # select branch
fi
```

and use konsole or konsole_select_branch whether you want to choose a branch or just open a tab or window.

Comment: it works, the only strange thing is that when I execute through Alt + F2 "konsole", it doesn't show the switch case for the branches.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a script in `.bashrc` which partly overwrite `.bashrc`; the zsh autocompletion facility does something similar, e.g. maybe do something like

```
 if [ -f $HOME/.somebashthing; ]; then
    . $HOME/.somebashthing
 else
    read SOMETHING
    echo SOMEVAR=$SOMETHING > $HOME/.somebashthing
 fi
```

This is only a sketch; it is up to you to fill the details.